# First usage of the word "baby" to mean fetus or any synonym of fetus

Tags: etymology

Does anyone know of a source that would indicate the first (give or take) usage of the word "baby" to mean fetus or any synonym of fetus? Every reference I've found thus far points to the usual meanings, but none indicate this particular usage. Even so, "fetus" is listed as an alternate definition in the few dictionaries I've checked.

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Comment: I'm not sure if the word "baby" ever *means* "fetus", any more than the word "person" means "adult". Rather, it's that fetuses are considered to be babies, or conceptualized as babies, in the usual sense of that word. ("Unborn infant" is attested since at least the 1600s.)

Comment: The synonymous expression ["**unborn baby**"](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22unborn+baby%22&biw=1366&bih=677&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1830&tbm=bks) was used as early as 1820, if that's any help.

Comment: However, the expression [**"unborn Infant"**](https://books.google.it/books?id=jrpjAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA237&dq=%22unborn+infant%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9ht_v7dXJAhVLPxQKHfFjC8M4FBDoAQhEMAY#v=onepage&q=%22unborn%20infant%22&f=false) is older, the link is from a book dated 1716

Comment: I've only seen ruakh's comment, so I've checked and found a 1655 reference from a book titled [Anabaptism routed](https://books.google.it/books?id=Xt0CAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA59&dq=%22unborn+infant%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN8ZHW8dXJAhXKsxQKHbKODLM4ChDoAQgxMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22unborn%20infant%22&f=false)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Great finds. Why don't you post them as an answer?

Comment: A.P. I've "retired" :) I was going to link my response to a comment I left at a disgruntled user's post but it's been deleted. Pity, 'cos it was quite a good punchline of mine. But, irrelevant, I suppose. **@ruakh** should post an answer, he came up with the idea of "unborn infant" first.

Comment: @ruakh No doubt you're right that the word "baty" never means "fetus". On the other hand, I think the word "child" means exactly that in the phrase "with child".

Comment: Pro-life campaigners seem to regard a zygote (unimplanted fertilised egg), let alone an embryo or foetus, as a child deserving of protection. I think "baby" is the overall term for all stages up to toddler.

Answer (score 2):

[Fetus](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fetus&allowed_in_frame=0) was used to refer to a newborn child also in Latin:

> - In Latin, fetus sometimes was transferred figuratively to the newborn creature itself, or used in a sense of "offspring, brood" (as in Horace's "Germania quos horrida parturit Fetus").

The Pregnancy Terms Glossary of Medical Terminology defines:

***[Fetus](http://www.baby2see.com/medical/medical_terms.html)*** as:

> - Medical term for the baby before it is born, ie when still in the uterus.

the *AHD and the Collins Dictionary* give one definition of 
***[baby](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/baby)*** as:

> - An unborn child; a fetus.

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=baby%20fetus&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbaby%20fetus%3B%2Cc0)*** show usage of the expression ***baby fetus***   from the 60's.

Comment: The term *fetus* can also be spelled as *foetus* I think that's BrEng spelling. Well worth seeing if there's any difference in the Ngram thingy.

Comment: No evidence for 'baby foetus' on Ngram.

Comment: ***Fetus vs foetus in BrE*** : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fetus%2Cfoetus&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfetus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfoetus%3B%2Cc0 - ***Fetus vs Foetus in AmE***: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fetus%2Cfoetus&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfetus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfoetus%3B%2Cc0 - no 'baby foetus' in BrE.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think this has ever been done.  Fetus is an exact development stage.  Baby is the generic catch all term.  Thus you have the implication arrow pointing in the wrong direction.  Fetus implies baby.  But "baby" might mean a 5 year old boy or my fluffy eared Beagle.

Comment: I agree. Pro-life campaigners seem to regard a zygote (unimplanted fertilised egg), let alone an embryo or foetus, as a child deserving of protection. I think "baby" is the overall term for all stages up to toddler at least.

Answer (score 0):

According to Online Etymology Dictionary, *baby* comes from [*babe*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=babe&allowed_in_frame=0):

> late 14c., short for ***baban*** (early 13c.), which probably is ***imitative
> of baby talk (see babble)***, however in many languages the cognate word
> means "old woman" (compare Russian babushka "grandmother," from baba
> "peasant woman").
>
> Crist crid in cradil, "moder, baba!" [John Audelay,
> c. 1426]
>
> Now mostly superseded by its diminutive form baby. Used
> figuratively for "a childish person" from 1520s. Meaning "attractive
> young woman" is 1915, college slang. Babe in the woods is from 1795.

The word [***fetus***](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/fetus) is rather a medical term like *embryo*. Its usage picked up sharply around '60s and '70s when the abortion rights movement peaked as the linked [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fetus%2Cembryo%2Cunborn+child&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfetus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembryo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunborn%20child%3B%2Cc0) shows.

> the ***developing young*** in the uterus, specifically the unborn offspring
> in the ***postembryonic period***, which in humans is from the third month
> after fertilization until birth

[Miller-Keane Encyclopedia and Dictionary of Medicine, Nursing, and Allied Health, Seventh Edition]

*Unborn baby* and *unborn child* could be synonymous with *fetus*. Depending on context, [*baby*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/baby) could also mean a *human fetus* as defined in Dictionary.Com. However, it would be very difficult to pinpoint when *baby* started to mean a *human fetus* as *baby* has a lot of different meanings including *attractive young woman*.